# Could the US Air Force ever replace the Thunderbird pilots with drones?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, airshow, us-air-force

Would it be possible or practical for the US Air Force to replace the Thunderbird pilots with drones?  The drones could perform more difficult maneuvers and do them more precisely.

The University of Pennsylvania is successfully working on small-scale formation flying.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this is definitely an opinion storm in the making.  Personally, I'd say "what's the point of formation drone flying, it's easy".  VTC.

Comment: Sure... as soon as they're trying to recruit drones to join the Air Force, instead of people.

Comment: AFAIK, drones are ages away from being able to do formation flying at all, not to mention with the sort of precision decent human pilots can.

Comment: As a pilot, I view flight demonstration teams as a superb display of the skill of the pilots. Take the pilots out, and there would be no airmanship for me to be awed by. Perhaps if I were involved in the hardware and software development to enable drones to do that, I might then be able to generate more enthusiasm.

Comment: @JanHudec please define "ages", since this is already occurring on a small scale.  https://youtu.be/YQIMGV5vtd4?t=45s

Comment: @Simon I think the engineers working on the drone formation flying project above would argue with your assertion that it's easy.  I suspect it is actually hard.  Moreover, the complexity of the formation tasks could always be increased to make them hard.

Comment: @Terry the purpose of a warplane is not to exist for the pilot - rather the pilot exists to fly the warplane's military mission.

Comment: @steampowered, but it's not cool to see a machine do it.  It's expected by the general public.  The average person doesn't understand machine learning or AI.  They are in awe that a human has the skill to be able to fly with such precision.  In addition, people want to be able to talk to the people that fly them.

Comment: @TUMBLEWEED they could meet the engineers who create and maintain the technology.  There is always a human face behind technology when you dig deep enough.  Perhaps this would be a more relevant recruiting tool for a futuristic fighting force, rather than inspiring people to desire a job as a fighter pilot which is becoming less and less common.

Comment: @steampowered The Thunderbirds don't exist to fight wars. They exist to impress people. Drones are objectively worse at this than the badass military pilots with nerves of steel who can also stand and chat next to their planes before and after their performance. And they don't just exist to recruit fighter pilots; fighter pilots have *never* been the dominant portion of the air force. In fact, impressive stuff like that increases enlistment as well, and enlisted men aren't even *eligible* to fly planes. Basically, the Thunderbirds are just about the worst possible application of UAVs.

Comment: @steampowered "Less and less common"?  Would you mind quantifying your answer, since, to my knowledge, drones haven't replaced anyone yet.

Comment: @RhinoDriver I have a few friends flying the viper in the CAF, and they all tell me flying time has been getting more scarce between 2011 and 2015.  Meanwhile they are getting recruited into UAS jobs all the time.  I don't have a quantitative way to back it up, just what people say.  By the way, I half posted this as a joke - I don't like it either.  But everybody knows it's the future (even crusty old F-4 pilots, ha ha)

Comment: @steampowered Note that I prefaced my remark with "As a pilot...." Of course you are correct that the ultimate purpose of a warplane is not for the benefit of the pilots, but from my standpoint as a pilot enjoying a flight demonstration, my enjoyment is not based on the ultimate purpose, but on the piloting. When I was a 747 captain, the fact that I was getting 400+ people to where they wanted to go was incidental to the real reason I was doing it, that being because I loved to fly. Frankly, they could have paid me half of what they were paying me and I still would have done it.

Comment: @cpast, I do think selling recruitment to the modern USAF with F-16 flying in fingertip is most likely a relic from the 1950's which adds little value.  More importantly, it miscommunicates the opportunities which exist in the AF.  Fighter jets are being marginalized in the AF.  Both bomber and fighter roles will be replaced with robotic aircraft in the next 20 to 30 years.  Kids watching the thunderbirds think they are likely to work with F-16 flying in fingertip, but this is less and less the case.

Comment: @steampowered Meh, I've talked to engineers that are on the projects designing these drones, specifically the carrier variant, and they said there aren't even plans yet to design a strike fighter replacement. I don't doubt flying jobs become more scarce in a draw down, and with UAVs coming online I'm sure it looks like a 1 for 1 trade, but I think they are probably unrelated statistics. Especially considering there isn't an unmanned variant of the Viper anywhere to replace it.  That's not to say a predator can't perform some of the functions, but still, we're a long ways off.

Comment: @steampowered But I'm with you, drones are the worst.

Comment: @steampowered In the entire history of the United States Air Force, it has literally never been the case that fighter pilots were representative of the branch (nor are drone operators; most personnel are neither). The Thunderbirds do not exist to give a representative picture of the Air Force. "Fighter pilot" isn't even representative of the Thunderbirds; they have 8 pilots and over 120 non-pilots. The Thunderbirds exist to be cool; representativeness isn't the point. Drones simply *are not as impressive*. You can say they should be, but they aren't, and so it's a terrible choice for the team.

Comment: Incidentally, the USAF has 1,284 UAV pilots on active duty and 426 in the ANG (none in the reserves), according to their demographics query tool. They have 2,405 fighter pilots on active duty. There are 2,841 doctors on active duty. Just giving you an idea of how little the Thunderbirds are intended to represent the typical Air Force member.

Comment: @cpast trends and the rate of change of this value is more relevant than today's value.  I'm surprised the populations are that close.  I expect UAV/RPA population will pass other communities in the years to come.

Comment: @steampowered But they won't. Not anywhere enough to be "representative." More officers aren't pilots of any stripe than are pilots of any stripe. And 80% of the entire active duty Air Force are enlisted, who aren't even eligible to become pilots. Pilots are not and have never been the majority of the USAF. Drone pilots aren't and won't be. Since the Thunderbirds are about coolness and not at all about representativeness, there's no reason to care about representativeness of human vs. drone pilots.

Comment: @steampowered The Air Force is actually undergoing a shortage of fighter pilots right now.  They're dropping them like crazy currently.  Additionally they still have the $250K bonus for 11Fs if they stay in 10 more years.

Answer (score 1):

Tight formation flying can be done with stock aircraft and skilled pilots, but drones would need additional sensors and new code in their [FCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_flight_control_system). Also, you can fly aerobatics even with gliders, but only when a decent power-to-weight ratio is reached, aerobatics becomes a spectator sport. I think it is frivolous for the US Air Force to pay for the development and additional equipment to make drones fly aerobatic displays, but few Air Forces are known for an enlightened budget discipline. I expect, however, that this will be added first by a company producing drones, and for demonstration and marketing purposes, and then the taxpayer will fund this indirectly.

Formation flying was a needed skill for bomber pilots, back then when their bundled defensive weapons provided the best protection against fighter attacks, and aerobatic flying was and still is valuable for fighter pilots. In the days of missiles and UAVs, neither formation flying nor aerobatics are necessary skills anymore, so in a way aerobatic formations are a quaint relic from the last millennium.

**To answer the "could" aspect of your question:** No, not directly. This would need modifications to existing drones.

**To answer the "ever" aspect:** Once the services field UCAVs (unmanned combat drones) with a [good power-to-weight ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_X-45), having them fly aerobatic displays looks almost unavoidable, but I expect it will not be the Air Force, but the marketing department of a big contractor driving this.

Comment: apparently the USAF is already flying F-16's unmanned  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewoCUFne3MI

Comment: @steampowered … to then shoot at them, yes. Nothing new here.

Comment: @ Peter Kämpf   Remote controlling an aircraft for targeting in general at Tyndall is not new - RF-4 have been used for many years.  But the RQ-F16 is relatively new.   First one 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

UAVs and UCAVs can be programmed to fly in formation as has already been demonstrated. There may be military applications for this capability. A tactic used by Luftwaffe "sturmgruppe" units against US bomber formations in World War Two was the "company front" assault in which the heavily armoured FW190 fighters, flying in a close line abreast formation, would approach a bomber formation from the rear, dividing the defensive firepower, and then break up at the last moment to attack individual bombers. UCAVs could potentially use similar tactics effectively against enemy ground, naval or air forces in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, the Thunderbirds mission is recruitment. A drone formation is absolutely possible and would be quite the show, but it would not do much for recruiting civilians if the drones were the only part of the show.

Some might suggest using RPAs to bring a human aspect back into it, but that would not be a great idea either, at least with current technology. Formation flying relies heavily on recognizing small discrepancies and making small corrections to achieve that "locked" appearance. RPAs, like the [MQ-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Atomics_MQ-9_Reaper), have low latency if the operator and aircraft are in the same area, but there still is *some* latency with the signal being transmitted, translated, read, and displayed. In addition, unless the operator is wearing some sort of augmented/virtual reality headset and the aircraft has some 180+ degree camera, the spatial awareness will be severely degraded. Finally, our current RPAs are loiter aircraft, so they are really not fit for being in formation. What I mean is that the wide wings and light-weight design make the aircraft prone to the effects of turbulence, convection, probably even the propwash of the other aircraft in formation.

All that being said, I think once we get the jet-propelled drones more developed and trusted, we might be seeing them in airshows. The [MQ-25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_MQ-25_Stingray), a refueling, carrier-based drone, would be a prime candidate for a refueling demo (the ones where the fuel recipient [isn't actually connected](https://www.stripes.com/polopoly_fs/1.101919.1274114452!/image/387868933.jpg_gen/derivatives/landscape_900/387868933.jpg)).

Comment: Who said anything about replacing them?  Why not have both?  For lower budget, smaller shows, send in the drones!  Absolutely love the formation photo.  Why not?

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni , the original poster alluded to replacing them.

Comment: Copy that,  I am offering an alternative.

Comment: Then the phrase is "Who says we have to replace them?", not "Who said anything about replacing them?". Nobody said we *have* to replace them, but OP clearly brought it up as a possibility.

Comment: I like the design so much, why not put pilots in them?